# Finite coloring of an interval

Tags: real-analysis, coloring

Two real functions, $f$ and $g$, are defined on the interval $[-1,1]$. Each point $x$ in the interval is colored in one of 3 colors:

- Red - if $f(x)>g(x)$
- Blue - if $f(x)=g(x)$
- Green - if $f(x)<g(x)$

Let $N(f,g)$ be the number of intervals of different colors. I.e., if $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=0$ then there are 3 intervals: green $[-1,0)$, blue $[0,0]$, red $(0,1]$.

What conditions on the functions $f$ and $g$ are necessary and sufficient to guarantee that $N(f,g)$ is finite?

Answer (score 2):

If the number of crossings $f(x)= g(x) $ is finite we could still have a pathological function such that such as $f=1$ for $x$ rational and $f = -1$ for $x$ irrational and $g = -f,$ in which case there are only finitely many points of equality but infinitely many changes of color.

On the other hand if we require finitely many changes of sign for $f-g$ and include $f-g=0$ to $f-g\neq 0$ as a change of sign (as well as $f<g$ to $f>g$) then this assures finitely many changes of color (hence finitely many different colored intervals).

A more basic way to avoid infinitely many intervals is to require $f,g$ be monotone and continuous. Continuity by itself is not sufficient. Monotonicity seems excessive in light of the above but I can't think of milder restrictions that don't invite counter-examples.

Comment: I have assumed "the number of intervals of different colors" counts red/blue/green/red as 4 intervals.

Comment: Is there a more basic property / term that describes such functions?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: The restriction of the second paragraph we might as well call the "avoid having infinite intervals" property. Maybe something like continuity plus (?) in the third paragraph could work although monotonicity seems excessive. This is a nice question and I hope you get other responses. The problem with basic answers is that there are a collection of pathological functions that can defeat desired properties in surprising ways. The challenge is to find something both suff. and necc.